# Clear cell contents when previous cell is changed

Tags: vba, excel

I am not familiar with VBA, and usually Google to try and find solutions, so bear with me.

What I want to achieve is: a cell in column M is cleared when the cell in column L (in the same row) is changed.  Right now I have the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "L3" Then Range("M3").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Which applies great when just using L3 & M3, but I can't figure out how to get it to apply to the entire column (or technically I need it to work for L3:L4000 and M3:M4000).  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get the Target's row and clear same row in Column M

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("M" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

sticking to your code as much as possible:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Left(Target.Address(, False), 1) = "L" Then Target.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it a tiny bit more responsive/faster, you can use the `.Column` and `.Row` properties:

```
If Target.Column = 12 And Target.Row >= 3 Then Target(, 2).ClearContents
```